# How can I find public images (like ubuntu) in Docker-Hub, using REST API?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-api

Previously I used

https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/search?q=ubuntu&n=1
and got

```
{"num_pages": 13196, "num_results": 13196, "results": [{"is_automated": false, "name": "ubuntu", "is_trusted": false, "is_official": true, "star_count": 4681, "description": "Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux operating system based on free software."}], "page_size": 1, "query": "ubuntu", "page": 1}
```

But now I got outdated images

How can I get it now?

I didn't find any information here: https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/api/docker-io_api/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason your using the search enpoint? If you know the names of the images you can query the tags

Comment: There are two main reasons:
1. there are multiple vendors of same open source service, 2. ability to search by part of name, or wildcard